# 2D String Array into 2D Int Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I want to convert the 2D string array into an integer 2D array. How to do that. i tried some things but i cant concentrate right now and id like to finish it today :D Thanks in advance.
So... here are all the values of the array:

```
parts[] []: 

[0] "25"
[1] "3"
[2] "18"

[0] "20"
[1] "12"
[2] "18"

[0] "1"
[1] "1"
[2] "15"

//string.length = 3;

String[] [] parts = new String[string.length][];
int[] [] stringToInt = new int[string.length][];

for(int a=0; a<string.length;a++){
    for(int b=0; b<3;b++){
      stringToInt[a] = Integer.parseInt(parts[a] [b]);    <---Error
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `stringToInt[a] = Integer.parseInt(parts[a] [b])` does? Are you sure you didn't miss there `[b]` somewhere? Also what error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Please try to be more specific. What error are you getting? Can you please post a [mcve]? Also this doesn't seem to be Processing code so I removed the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: "I can't concentrate right now" doesn't seem like quite the right reason to outsource this problem to us, thereby taking away our time from answering the questions of people who seriously tried and couldn't figure out the answer to a question.

Comment: Im new to Stack Overflow so i had problems with marking some passages of my code as code. Also, this IS Processing Code. What makes you think it isnt? If you mean the first lines of Code which indeed are no Code. But because as i said had problems marking those lines as non-code i marked it as code. And if i remember correctly, It was marked as code automatically and i couldnt change it because it was recognized as code. Concerning the "i cant concentrate": i thought i can ask questions when i have some? And this is a legitimate question or is it not? help me understand pls.

Comment: Sorry i answered all questions at once but i didnt see that more than one person asked a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems initializing the string array, and then defining the 2D int array.  This is probably what you meant to do:

```
String parts[][] = { { "25", "3", "18" }, { "20", "12", "18" }, { "1", "1", "15" } };

int[][] stringToInt = new int[parts.length][parts[0].length];

for (int a = 0; a < parts.length; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < parts[0].length; b++) {
        stringToInt[a][b] = Integer.parseInt(parts[a][b]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, first of all i wanna say that the "code" on top is not really part of the code i accidentally defined it as code here. Its the output of parts [ ] [ ]. i just wanted to show how it lookes like. Sry for the misunderstanding :D

And yes thanks very much. i forgot to initialize the Arrayrows...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cols = 3;
    int rows = 3;
    String [][] parts = new String[cols][rows];

    //init the 2d array
    parts[0][0] = "25";
    parts[0][1] = "3";
    parts[0][2] = "18";

    parts[1][0] = "20";
    parts[1][1] = "12";
    parts[1][2] = "18";

    parts[2][0] = "1";
    parts[2][1] = "1";
    parts[2][2] = "15";

    //the array you want
    int [][] intArray = new int [cols][rows];

    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){

        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
            intArray[c][r] = Integer.parseInt(parts[c][r]);
        }

    }


}
```

I'm thinking your error may be because you are giving `stringToInt[a]=` instead of `stringToInt[a][b]=`

Comment: Thanks for the submission of your comment. Yes you are right. I tried it with  stringToInt[a][b]= aswell but the reason it didnt work is that i forgot to initialize the rows of the 2D array....